# Can you submit the same grant proposal to two different funding organizations?

Tags: funding, research-proposal

I have recently submitted an EU grant proposal, the chances are low as it is very competitive, and I have just come across another fellowship (UK based) which is actually more suited to my field but the deadline is in a few days. Can I apply with the same research project proposal?

Before, anyone suggests, I checked similar questions: this thread is not useful as the funding organization is the same for them (not for me): [Can one submit overlapping grant proposals?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/153594/can-one-submit-overlapping-grant-proposals)

Comment: Do the organizations have any rules where this is covered?

Comment: Nothing in the guidelines,  it only mentions that I can't submit two very similar research proposals (even if they are years apart) - I would need to revise/edit, also I believe it goes in a turn it in check, e.g. is the text taken as is from published work etc.

Comment: It entirely depends on the institution's rules. Best to call them.

Comment: Organizational rules may cover part of the answer, but I'd also be curious about etiquette. This feels like submitting the same manuscript to two different journals at the same time, which is a big no-no whether or not the journal organizations are different. Is this a situation where you should withdraw one proposal application before submitting another?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin My concern is the etiquette as well, or rather I want to learn about the experiences of people. There is nothing covered about this explicitly so I don't think it is against the rules anyway. I don't agree with your later point however, I don't think it is the same as a journal manuscript. Proposals are not science, they don't have results, they don't have the finest details about methodology. I don't think they would even count as an abstract.  Proposals are proposals. Besides, journals do explicitly state you can't do this.

Comment: I read the eligibility by the way, and I can't really apply, but I still want to know. Given more time, of course it is best to create new content even if the topics overlap. And also, all proposals should be written with expectations of the funding agency in mind anyway so they will never be identical. But still I wonder if people send out very similar applications to different sources or not.

Comment: What kind of grant is that?  If it is, say, a Marie Curie, then this is an exclusive grant which funds you fully - you can only have one of those.  In that case, there is no issue in applying in several places and finally only taking up one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can propose for the same topic/ideas. But the EU and UK application process (even applications within the same "country") are different and they look for different things for you to submit. So you can and should reuse old proposals (as no one has the time to make completely new proposals for every submission) as a "base" but they do need to be tailored for each submission. For instance the relative amount of space you have to write about method/novelty/timeliness/impact etc as well as practical things like page limits, page format, supporting documentation etc.

Given most proposals are also for different lengths of time/number of people proposals gain differences even if they cover the same area.

There can be limits about whether you can have multiple applications at the same time, but applications will be explicit about the limits in the supporting documentation. If your not sure ask your university research grants team as they know the details inside and out.